# Ellipses before function calls in php / laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

So laravel contains some code that looks like this:

```
public function isClean($attributes = null)
{
    return ! $this->isDirty(...func_get_args());
}
```

The `...func_get_args()` is throwing php and causing a fatal error. I can't find any reference to using the ellipses before 'func_get_args' anywhere, what should it do or is it a bug?

Comment: [Argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) (Example #14)... introduced in PHP 5.6.0

Comment: @MarkBaker this should be an answer!